# Access element after append

Tags: jquery

I've read through every post I can find on this topic and have tried many "solutions" but it just doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
$(function () {

    var options = {
        source: [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            ],
        minLength: 2
    };  

    $('#btn_addline').on ("click", function () {

        // get existing line number and increment by one
        var linenum = parseInt ($('#numlines').val()) + 1;

        // update hidden numlines field with new value
        $('#numlines').val(linenum);

        // define new field names
        var line_field = 'report['+linenum+'][line]';
        var notes_field = 'report['+linenum+'][notes]';
        var contact_field = 'report['+linenum+'][contact]';

        var newLine = $('<tr> \
            <td><input name="'+line_field+'" id="'+line_field+'" type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" class="form" value="'+linenum+'" readonly="readonly" /></td> \
            <td><input name="'+notes_field+'" id="'+notes_field+'" type="text" size="96" maxlength="256" class="form" /></td> \
            <td><input name="'+contact_field+'" id="'+contact_field+'" onFocus="attach_autocomplete()" type="text" size="32" maxlength="32" class="form" value="test123" /></td> \
            </tr>');

        // append new line to table
        //$('#report_items').append(newLine);

        $('#report_items').append(newLine)
            .hide()
            .fadeIn('Normal', function() {
                $(this).find('#'+contact_field).val('test');
                //alert ($(this).find('#'+contact_field).val());
                alert (contact_field);
                alert ($('#'+contact_field).val());
            });

        //$('#'+contact_field).autocomplete(options);

    });
});
```

The new HTML is appended properly, however nothing I do can access those elements.  I've tried various suggestions throughout the site and am get frustrated now and am hoping for some help.

The third alert - `alert ($('#'+contact_field).val());` - returns "undefined".

To be clear, I have thoroughly gone through the list of similar questions, but have not found a solution.  It is very possible I am missing something obvious, or I don't quite understand the relation between appending elements and it's effect on the DOM, but in any case I could really use a hand here.

Cheers.

Comment: Show us your HTML, or use http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Will add HTML.  And setting up jsfiddle right now as well.

Comment: I suggest you replace `[` `]` from your id's and use underscores `_`, like `'report_' + linenum + '__line_'`

Comment: I originally started that route, however my ajax backend needs to receive the information as an array.

Comment: @Luke Pittman: that's right, you can keep the same format for `name` attribute, and change the `id` attribute. (On server side only the `name` attribute is used to map data)

Comment: Ahhhh, yes, I could.  I will try that out right now.  Here is the jsfiddle in the mean time:  http://jsfiddle.net/xBRk2/

Comment: @RaraituL - Thank you.  Making that small change solved the problem.

Comment: @RaraituL I wish I could mark your comments as a correct answer to give you the points.  But since Billyonecan posted an 'actual' answer I will mark that one.  His solution was correct as well.  Thanks for your help nonetheless.

Comment: @LukePittman: Don't worry, i don't do this for points. Glad i could helped you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have special characters within your selector. You'd need to escape those with two backslashes `\\`:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar").

[Check out the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Thanks.  I was under the impression that didn't apply when you used a variable in a selector as I did.  I tried your suggestion, however I got exactly the same result.  I am trying to get it up on jsfiddle right now.

Comment: You won't be able to change your variable, otherwise you'll end up with backslashes on the element itself, and the selector won't select anything. You could create another one, or write directly in to the selector

Comment: I've updated your fiddle to show you what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/deifwud/xBRk2/1/

Comment: Ooooh.  Okay, I see now.  I really should have been able to see that.  But I understand how it works now.  Thank you.